# Using Facebook Login with Heroku Review Apps

Tags: facebook, heroku, facebook-login

Now that Facebook [requires](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/) all valid redirect URIs to be manually entered, does anyone know of a way to get [Heroku review apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps) to work with Facebook Login, since each app is dynamically generated based on the pull request, ex `https://app-staging-pr-114.herokuapp.com`.

Comment: Not possible, you have to manually enter all redirect URIs in the settings.

Comment: Even main staging apps get marked as abusive and malicious. Hope there is a better way than to contact facebook support.